# Limit amount of allocateable memory for process

Tags: memory, windows-service, quota

I've got a windows service written in C#, that does some heavy work (irrelevant for the question) running on a remote machine (Windows Server 2008).

Every now an then a client application contacts the service. The service starts its work and possibly consumes large bunch of memory. It releases the consumed memory after the work is done. Everything fine so far, no memory leaks or the like.
But unfortunately the service allocates almost all memory available if multiple clients contact it (which is basically ok, since it does hard work). The drawback is that then there's no memory available for other services that run on that machine.

So is there a way to limit or constrain the amount of memory my service may allocate? Is it somehow possible to declare, say, take up to 50% of the machine's memory but not more?
Something like this is possible for processes hosted in IIS, but mine is a 'ususal' windows service.

Comment: compile the C# service as x86/32Bit to only allow 2GB memory usage.

Comment: Well, although this sounds a bit hacky to me this _might be_ an option, if the remote machine had more than 2GB of memory. But in my case, the machine only has a total of ~1.5GB at hand.

Comment: only 1.5GB for a server? Install more RAM

Comment: Well, it's no front-facing server with heavy load. It's a small one for internal purposes.